# Can Clang be used to parse c/c++ files and return class info (names, methods, params)?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, autocomplete, ide, clang

I'm going to add autocomplete for IDE and Clang is known to be very user-friendly. Can it be used to parse c/c++ files on-fly and return class info (names, methods, params)?

Comment: look for ASTConsumer in clang API. This should help: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/06/08/basic-source-to-source-transformation-with-clang/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and you can use several APIs: clang binary, libclang shared library (a.k.a. clang-c), internal APIs (they can be changed between clang versions), python bindings to clang-c.

Prefer python bindings or clang-c.